# Datetime formatting with torndb python

Tags: python, mysql, datetime, tornado, mysql-python

I have a simple query that converts a VARCHAR column to a datetime (the one I provide here is an even simplified version that illustrates the problem). When executed directly in mysql the query runs as expected:

```
mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('01:35 PM', '%h:%i %p') as t;
+----------+
| t        |
+----------+
| 13:35:00 |
+----------+
```

However, when I run the exact same query in torndb:

```
row = conn.get("SELECT STR_TO_DATE('01:35 PM', '%%h:%%i %%p') as t")
print ">>", row.t
```

I get the following warning (conn is correctly constructed using torndb.Connection):

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/torndb.py:226: Warning: Incorrect datetime value: '01:35 PM' for function str_to_date
  return cursor.execute(query, kwparameters or parameters)
>> None
```

Looking further into mysqldb, it seem that the problem is related to it:

```
conn = db.connect("localhost", 'xxx')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT STR_TO_DATE('01:35 PM', '%%h:%%i %%p') as t")
main:1: Warning: Incorrect datetime value: '01:35 PM' for function str_to_date
1L
```

However, when I remove the double %%, it works fine:

```
c.execute("SELECT STR_TO_DATE('01:35 PM', '%h:%i %p') as t")
1L
c.fetchone()
(datetime.timedelta(0, 48900),)
```

Not sure what's going on here...

Comment: Apparently, the problem is in the argument torndb passes to initialize mysqldb - sql_mode="TRADITIONAL". Removing this solves the issue, but I'm not sure why this causes the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Torndb turns on SQL mode "TRADITIONAL", which enables a number of options on the mysql server.  Among them are NO_ZERO_DATE and NO_ZERO_IN_DATE, which make the server stricter about invalid DATEs and DATETIMEs.  In this case STR_TO_DATE should be returning a TIME, not a DATETIME, so it is not supposed to be affected, but it looks like internally it's triggering some sort of check on the absent date portion of the timestamp.  This looks like a bug in mysql.  The simplest workaround is to not use TRADITIONAL mode (or at least to unset the NO_ZERO_IN_DATE flag).

Comment: can we do it in torndb?